# Unknown error while debuggin rust application in VS Code

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to debug a fairly large rust project in VS code.

The launch.json has this:

```
    {
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug executable 'rpfm_ui'",
        "cargo": {
            "args": [
                "build",
                "--bin=rpfm_ui",
                "--package=rpfm_ui"
            ],
            "filter": {
                "name": "rpfm_ui",
                "kind": "bin"
            }
        },
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
```

But when I try to run the application I get the following

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 9.53s
Raw artifacts:
{
  fileName: 'c:\\Users\\ole_k\\Desktop\\rpfm-master\\target\\debug\\rpfm_ui.exe',
  name: 'rpfm_ui',
  kind: 'bin'
}
Filtered artifacts: 
{
  fileName: 'c:\\Users\\ole_k\\Desktop\\rpfm-master\\target\\debug\\rpfm_ui.exe',
  name: 'rpfm_ui',
  kind: 'bin'
}
configuration: {
  type: 'lldb',
  request: 'launch',
  name: "Debug executable 'rpfm_ui'",
  args: [],
  cwd: '${workspaceFolder}',
  relativePathBase: 'c:\\Users\\ole_k\\Desktop\\rpfm-master',
  program: 'c:\\Users\\ole_k\\Desktop\\rpfm-master\\target\\debug\\rpfm_ui.exe',
  sourceLanguages: [ 'rust' ]
}
Listening on port 49771
[adapter\src\terminal.rs:99] FreeConsole() = 1
[adapter\src\terminal.rs:100] AttachConsole(pid) = 1
[adapter\src\terminal.rs:104] FreeConsole() = 1
[2020-06-27T20:43:04Z ERROR codelldb::debug_session] process launch failed: unknown error
Debug adapter exit code=0, signal=null.
```

I have also seen this:

- PS C:\Users\ole_k\Desktop\rpfm-master>  & 'c:\Users\ole_k.vscode\extensions\vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.5.3\adapter\codelldb.exe' 'terminal-agent' '--port=49628'
  Error: Os { code: 10061, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." }
- [2020-06-27T20:29:08Z ERROR codelldb::debug_session] process launch failed: unknown error

If I run the application from the terminal inside vs code (cargo run --bin rpfm_ui) it works.
There are some external dependencies which are in folders outside of the root folder.
I can debug other projects in the solution which share a lot of the code, but not the external dependencies.
I can debug other projects.
I am running as administrator.

Any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Maybe removing target folder will help?

Comment: The CWD attribute? I tried, but same error

Comment: No, I mean cargo's one: _c:\\Users\\ole_k\\Desktop\\rpfm-master\\target_. Sometimes it solves some weird compilation problems.